# URL not accessible from browser but I can post data using form post

Tags: php

I have a form

```
<form name="pform" method="post" action="http://ednrd.ae/portal/pls/portal/INIMM_DB.DBPK_VISAVALIDITY.PROCESS_QUERY_STATUS_REDIR">
<input type ="hidden" name="p_qry_no" value="2104313370691">
<input type ="hidden" name="p_qry_type" value="1">
<input type ="hidden" name="p_firstname" value="mumtaz">
<input type ="hidden" name="p_gender" value="1">
<input type ="hidden" name="p_nationality" value="203">
<input type ="hidden" name="p_dob" value="07-06-1991">
<input type="submit" value="submit">
```

when i submit the above form I can see the response, but when I access directly the url http://ednrd.ae/portal/pls/portal/INIMM_DB.DBPK_VISAVALIDITY.PROCESS_QUERY_STATUS_REDIR

type typing it in the browser I can't see anything ? error page is displayed 404

thanks in advance for the solution.

Comment: what the log file says

Answer (score 0):

There is probably only `POST` method handled. `GET` is ignored and returned `404` HTTP status.